# How to exclude a single value from Groupby method using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe where I have transformed all NaN to 0 for a specific reason. In doing another calculation on the df, my group by is picking up a 0 and making it a value to perform the counts on. Any idea how to get python and pandas to exclude the 0 value? In this case the 0 represents a single row in the data. Is there a way to exclude all 0's from the groupby?

My groupby looks like this

```
  +----------------+----------------+-------------+
  | Team           | Method         |  Count      |
  +----------------+----------------+-------------+
  | Team 1         | Automated      |           1 |
  | Team 1         | Manual         |          14 |
  | Team 2         | Automated      |           5 |
  | Team 2         | Hybrid         |           1 |
  | Team 2         | Manual         |          25 |
  | Team 4         | 0              |           1 |
  | Team 4         | Automated      |           1 |
  | Team 4         | Hybrid         |          13 |
  +----------------+----------------+-------------+
```

My code looks like this (after importing excel file)

```
  df = df1.filnna(0)
  a = df[['Team', 'Method']]
  b = a.groupby(['Team', 'Method']).agg({'Method' : 'count'}
```

Comment: why can't you filter the df prior to grouping? so `a = df.loc[df['Method'] !=0, ['Team', 'Method']]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd filter the df prior to grouping:

```
In [8]:
a = df.loc[df['Method'] !=0, ['Team', 'Method']]
b = a.groupby(['Team', 'Method']).agg({'Method' : 'count'})
b
Out[8]:
                Method
Team Method           
1    Automated       1
     Manual          1
2    Automated       1
     Hybrid          1
     Manual          1
4    Automated       1
     Hybrid          1
```

Here we only select rows where method is not equal to `0`

compare against without filtering:

```
In [9]:
a = df[['Team', 'Method']]
b = a.groupby(['Team', 'Method']).agg({'Method' : 'count'})
b

Out[9]:
                Method
Team Method           
1    Automated       1
     Manual          1
2    Automated       1
     Hybrid          1
     Manual          1
4    0               1
     Automated       1
     Hybrid          1
```

Comment: Is it possible to filter out multiple columns simultaneously?  I have another columns, 'type', with the same issue of having a 0.

Comment: sure the generic form would be `a = df.loc[(df['col_1'] !=0) | (df['col_2'] != 0), ['Team', 'Method']]` this assumes that you don't want any rows with `0` in either of those columns

Answer (score 0):

You need the `filter`.

> The `filter` method returns a subset of the original object. Suppose
>   we want to take only elements that belong to groups with a group sum
>   greater than 2.

Example:

> In [94]: sf = pd.Series([1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3])
>
> In [95]: sf.groupby(sf).filter(lambda x: x.sum() > 2) Out[95]:  3    3
>   4    3 5    3 dtype: int64

[Source](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html).

Comment: How would I apply the filter to my data above?